# Does Epic Spell Wars actually contain profanity?

Tags: epic-spell-wars

I'm trying to judge the suitability of Epic Spell Wars for one of my kids and wanted to know if the sticker on the front was accurate?

Having watched the table-top episode there was a lot of swearing from the players but it wasn't obvious that the cards were actually the cause, just the general setup and flavour (Pisster and testikill for example).

Answer (score 4):

No, aside from the rulebook's preamble, it does not contain profanity.

Samples:

- Sir Lootzor's // Polished // Snakedance
- Ben Voodoo's // Boulder-iffic // Bedazzlement
- Pam and Hecuba's // Two-faced // Cone of Acid
- Midnight Merlin's // Devilicious // Power Vortex
- Whirly Do's // Burst-o-Ramic // Meatier Swarm

At worst, it's just a couple of cards that can be removed.

---

The rulebook of the sequel (Rumble at Castle Tentakill) is clean, and the following are the only offending cards:

- Bitch Witch
- Sexsquatch
- Dr Gravelovers (the art is iffy)
- Auto-Erotic
- The F-U Suit (spelled exactly like this)

Comment: Cheers - how about the rule set - I've had mixed reports on that varying from "a little" to "littered with"...

Comment: Polished Snakedance sounds rather vulgar, but *only if you already know it's vulgar*. It seems unlikely to introduce anything vulgar into the mind of someone who wouldn't put that together.

Comment: The question was about profanity, not vulgarity. There is some vulgarity (such as aforementioned "testikill"), but nothing worse than a kid would already be using.

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, I wasn't too upset with the innuendo, etc. it was more explicit swearing I'm after.

Comment: Don't worry about the rules, I've found them on the [publishers site](http://www.cryptozoic.com/sites/default/files/uploads/files/epic_spell_wars_rulebook.pdf).

Comment: The introduction for Rumble at Castle Tentakill contains at least 8 swear words. Also one of the wizards is named "Fu-king".